# Convergence rate of fourier partial sum

Tags: fourier-analysis

Hi there,

I am looking for the proofs of convergence rate in Section 4 of the following artical

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series

in wikipedia. Could someone please point me to the correct books or references on the proofs of these results?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you checked the reference which is given there? However, looks like off-topic here (see http://mathoverflow.net/faq).

Comment: Agree this is off-topic, but here's an additional suggestion: Rivlin, *An Introduction to the Approximation of Functions*.

Comment: Hi Dirk and Mark. The question seems to be off topic since I didn't put it in the right way. The question should be how to prove these results. If you have the suggestions for the proofs, please advise. Many thanks.

Mark, I will take a look at your suggestions.

Comment: Hi Mark,

Yes the detailed proof is in Rivlin. Thanks very much. I really appreciate your help.